# Full-text search with Meteor.js and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am experimenting with Meteor.js and looking for a full-text search engine that can run on Meteor/MongoDB server. It seems that Meteor has not developed this feature.

I wonder if there is an existing solution for adding full-text search to Meteor app.

The only thing I can find is [MongoLantern](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mongolantern/), which has node.js API. How should I go about adding MongoLantern to my Meteor app?

Comment: This is tangential to your question, but there seems to be buzz about ElasticSearch which has a JS API: https://github.com/fullscale/elastic.js.  I also ran across a couple of Mongo related NPM modules for fulltext search: https://npmjs.org/package/mongoose-fulltext and https://npmjs.org/package/mongoose-fts

Comment: Thanks mjhm, ElasticSearch is cool. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB 2.4 will have a full text search in it. [Guide can be found here.](http://blog.mongohq.com/blog/2013/01/22/first-week-with-mongodb-2-dot-4-development-release/)

If you are prepared to run the development releases you can download [MongoDB 2.3 now](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads) - it contains text search.

**Update:** MongoDB 2.4 has been released. Text search is described as Beta.

The guide for [text search is here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/text-search/) and the [`mongod` must be run like this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-text-search/)

```
mongod --setParameter textSearchEnabled=true
```

Comment: Thanks andy. That would be the best.

Comment: But, according to the Mongo docs, the text indices only work with the text() method. I think meteor.js doesn't support that yet.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no way to enable text search with the mock Mongo that Meteor uses during dev. But I guess I can point to my real MongoDB during dev.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://lunrjs.com/. That might also help in getting the near-instant performance of real Meteor app.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at:

https://github.com/Crenshinibon/spomet

It's a Meteor native package to provide full-text search. It has an easy to include search-box with autocompletion.

You can read a tutorial about an extended example application here:

http://shiggyenterprises.wordpress.com/2013/09/28/developing-a-full-text-search-enabled-meteor-app/

Answer (score 0):

There is also another way to implement a solution with Meteor. It's [Search Source](https://github.com/meteorhacks/search-source).

It's a kind of **typeahead** but without the UI part. It exposes a reactive datasource where you can use it to build the UI with Blaze as you need.

- Here's a demo app: https://instant-search-demo.meteor.com/

Above app is an instant search app to search Meteor packages. How it can build with search source is documented in [this](https://meteorhacks.com/implementing-an-instant-search-solution-with-meteor.html) article

In brief this is how search source works:

#### In client, create a source

```
var options = {
  keepHistory: 1000 * 60 * 5,
  localSearch: true
};
var fields = ['packageName', 'description'];

PackageSearch = new SearchSource('packages', fields, options);
```

#### Then in the server define the search source

```
SearchSource.defineSource('packages', function(searchText, options) {
  var options = {sort: {isoScore: -1}, limit: 20};

  if(searchText) {
    var regExp = buildRegExp(searchText);
    var selector = {packageName: regExp, description: regExp};
    return Packages.find(selector, options).fetch();
  } else {
    return Packages.find({}, options).fetch();
  }
});

function buildRegExp(searchText) {
  // this is dumb implementation
  var parts = searchText.trim().split(' ');
  return new RegExp("(" + parts.join('|') + ")", "ig");
}
```

#### Now get the data source and render it

```
Template.searchResult.helpers({
  getPackages: function() {
    return PackageSearch.getData({
      transform: function(matchText, regExp) {
        return matchText.replace(regExp, "<b>$&</b>")
      },
      sort: {isoScore: -1}
    });
  }
});
```

#### Finally do the search

```
PackageSearch.search("the text to search");
```

You can learn more about how each of the above works with from the [documentation](https://github.com/meteorhacks/search-source).