# Implementing MongoDB 2.4's full text search in a Meteor app

Tags: javascript, mongodb, search, meteor

I'm looking into adding full text search to a Meteor app. I know MongoDB now supports this feature, but I have a few questions about the implementation:

- What's the best way to enable the text search feature (`textSearchEnabled=true`) in a Meteor app?
- Is there a way to add an index (`db.collection.ensureIndex()`) from within your app?
- How can you run a Mongo command (i.e. `db.quotes.runCommand( "text", { search: "TOMORROW" } )`) from within a Meteor app?

Since my goal is to add search to [Telescope](http://telesc.pe), I'm searching for a "plug-and-play" implementation that requires minimal command line magic and could even work on Heroku or *.meteor.com.

Comment: Text search is a preview only in Mongo 2.4. As such, I don't believe it has been exposed.

Comment: I know it hasn't been exposed officially, but that doesn't mean there aren't ways to do it.

Comment: Text search is not exposed. It's open source, so you could add what you need and host it yourself. The text search hasn't been "proven" and isn't likely to be better than ElasticSearch/Solr/Lucene search engines.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567856/full-text-search-with-meteor-js-and-mongodb

Comment: wondering if this answer is still the best one as of September 2014?

Answer (score 27):

The simplest way without editing any Meteor code is to use your own mongodb. Your `mongodb.conf` should look something like this (on Arch Linux it is found at `/etc/mongodb.conf`)

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
quiet = true
dbpath = /var/lib/mongodb
logpath = /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
logappend = true
setParameter = textSearchEnabled=true
```

The key line is `setParameter = textSearchEnabled=true`, which, as it states, enables text search.

Start `mongod` up

Tell meteor to use your `mongod` not its own by specifying the `MONGO_URL` environmental variable.

```
MONGO_URL="mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor" meteor
```

Now say you have collection called `Dinosaurs` declared say in `collections/dinosaurs.js`

```
Dinosaurs = new Meteor.Collection('dinosaurs');
```

To create an text index for the collection create a file `server/indexes.js`

```
Meteor.startUp(function () {
    search_index_name = 'whatever_you_want_to_call_it_less_than_128_characters'

    // Remove old indexes as you can only have one text index and if you add 
    // more fields to your index then you will need to recreate it.
    Dinosaurs._dropIndex(search_index_name);

    Dinosaurs._ensureIndex({
        species: 'text',
        favouriteFood: 'text'
    }, {
        name: search_index_name
    });
});
```

Then you can expose the search through a `Meteor.method`, for example in the file `server/lib/search_dinosaurs.js`.

```
// Actual text search function
_searchDinosaurs = function (searchText) {
    var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
    var future = new Future();
    Meteor._RemoteCollectionDriver.mongo.db.executeDbCommand({
        text: 'dinosaurs',
        search: searchText,
        project: {
          id: 1 // Only take the ids
        }
     }
     , function(error, results) {
        if (results && results.documents[0].ok === 1) {
            future.ret(results.documents[0].results);
        }
        else {
            future.ret('');
        }
    });
    return future.wait();
};

// Helper that extracts the ids from the search results
searchDinosaurs = function (searchText) {
    if (searchText && searchText !== '') {
        var searchResults = _searchEnquiries(searchText);
        var ids = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < searchResults.length; i++) {
            ids.push(searchResults[i].obj._id);
        }
        return ids;
    }
};
```

Then you can publish only documents that have been searched for in 'server/publications.js'

```
Meteor.publish('dinosaurs', function(searchText) {
    var doc = {};
    var dinosaurIds = searchDinosaurs(searchText);
    if (dinosaurIds) {
        doc._id = {
            $in: dinosaurIds
        };
    }
    return Dinosaurs.find(doc);
});
```

And the client side subscription would look something like this in `client/main.js`

```
Meteor.subscribe('dinosaurs', Session.get('searchQuery'));
```

Props to [Timo Brinkmann](https://github.com/teamoo) whose [musiccrawler project](https://github.com/teamoo/musiccrawler) was the source of most this knowledge.

Comment: brought it over here and gave you credit http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Fulltext_search

Comment: That's awesome! One thing to note: this publication won't be realtime, as in the user will never get new dinosaurs that match the search etc.

Comment: @TomColeman ah yes excellent point, as the explicit list of ids will restrict it.

Comment: I believe that in 065 _RemoteCollectionDriver is no longer accessible.Do you know if there's an alternative? Cheers.

Comment: @StephanTual Thimo Brinkmann points to using MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db.executeDbCommand on Google Groups https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/x9kYnO52Btg/YaWrYLZSKJQJ

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting something, but why not just return the full Dinosaurs objects in the search, rather than returning just the IDs and then doing another query?

Comment: Updated syntax as of 0.6.6.3.pre -- MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo._getCollection('my_collection')

Comment: Why do you have 'jms_jobs_search_index'? Shouldn't it be search_index_name instead?

Comment: @seb you're correct, my mistake, that was an artifact from the project code I was using. I've fixed it in the answer, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure it's best to publish/subscribe to this search, seems like a waste for most search functions, when a method call would be much less resource intensive. You have to deal with unsubscribing if your using a throttle on the search. I could see uses for pub/sub, but I don't think a general example like this is a good case. :p Just my 2c

Comment: @Jordan fair point, the sorts of searches that I have needed to do in Meteor apps so far are "filters" when you have a list and wanted to see only a certain kind, say a list of customer enquiries where you would want to see any updates to them live. But your use case is probably popular (or more popular) too.

Answer (score 2):

To create a text index and try to add like this I hope so it will be useful if there is still problem comment

From [docs.mongodb.org](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/return-text-queries-using-only-text-index/):

---

> Append scalar index fields to a text index, as in the following
>   example which specifies an ascending index key on username:
>
> ```
> db.collection.ensureIndex( { comments: "text",
>                              username: 1 } )
> ```
>
> Warning You cannot include multi-key index field or geospatial index
>   field.
>
> Use the project option in the text to return only the fields in the
>   index, as in the following:
>
> ```
> db.quotes.runCommand( "text", { search: "tomorrow",
>                                 project: { username: 1,
>                                            _id: 0
>                                          }
>                               }
>                     )
> ```
>
> **Note:** By default, the _id field is included in the result set. Since the example index did not include the _id field, you must
>   explicitly exclude the field in the project document.

Comment: -1 for copy&paste from [docs.mongodb.org](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/return-text-queries-using-only-text-index) without reference. +50 for rtfm. Question is imho still unanswered. Missing the meteor context.